# How to access the pact mock server dynamic port in JUnit test

Tags: spring-boot-test, spring-cloud-feign, pact

I need to know on which port the pact mock server is running at startup time of my test.

The reason is my Rest client is a spring openfeign client, and the only way I know how to change it's url to which it connects, is by setting an environment property.
So I know how to access the port inside my test, by passing a MockServer argument, but I'd like to do it before the test has started, when spring boot loads my application context.

It would be nice if pact would expose a property in the same way as wiremock does `wiremock.server.port`